# Не получается вывести дату в формате german

Tags: postgresql, запрос, denwer, дата, формат

Необходимо выводить даты (использую postgresql) в формате German, но упорно выводятся на странице в формате ISO, хотя в конфигр. файлах я поставила где нужно `SET DATESTYLE = German` (в файле  postgresql.conf, Postgres.php и даже в adodb-postgres64.inc.php) и при запросе в phpPGAdmin "show datestyle" показывает, что там German, DMY.

Такое чувство, что надо еще менять и в самом Денвере или php где-то?

Comment: Лучше всегда использовать явное приведение формата даты, т.е. получать даты через функции конвертации в строку https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Я так и делала в запросе, но всё-равно формат YYYY-MM-DD. Самое главное, если я такой же запрос запускаю в phpPgAdmin, то функция to_date и to_char работает

Comment: хм. тогда походу вы правы и это уже не БД виновата, а где то на клиенте что то меняет формат, надо подождать, может знатоки денвера найдутся...